# What type of tires and wheels do I need to make a PVC beach cart?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I would like to make a beach cart that supports 200lbs and uses this design [image: Beach Cart]

What type and dimension wheels and tires should I buy? I have a budget of $100.00 for the tires and wheels. I cannot afford expensive sand tires like Wheelez. Will All Terrain Tires (AT) sufficiently work in sand with the expected load?

Comment: Generally the fancy sand tires are so that you can get a lot of grip when using the tires to drive. For an unpowered cart like this tire type is far less important. You just want to spread the load as much as possible to minimize the amount they dig into the sand so as large and wide as your budget and design allows. Slicks or low tread designs are fine.

Comment: Aside from tire choice, I recommend moving the axle dead-center, assuming you can distribute the cargo mass evenly.  That will reduce the amount lifting force required to level the cart while transporting.

Comment: Also the pvc joints right near the tyre axles will be the most loaded ones, (100 lbs shear) I don't know if their specs and life is a good fit for the function.

Answer (score 3):

use big rubber inflatable wheel barrow tires for they are IMO the best for pushing or pulling through soft loose soil.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Pneumatic tires are a good option when you want to drive around the cart on sand. A pair will set you back by roughly $30. Also, they are easily available on amazon. The DIameter of 10 inches is a good choice to go with. There are numerous such tires available on amazon with different dimensions.

[image]

Many of the [top beach carts](https://amusingoutdoors.com/best-beach-cart/) also use such tires. As for driving around on sand, unless you get larger wheels, wet sand will require more effort. Unfortunately, the larger ones also cost more. However, on dry sand, these pneumatic tires work great. Before you make your final decision, it is a good idea to take into account a few factors:

- Diameter
- Load carrying capacity
- Construction material

Your budget is more than enough in a nutshell and also, pneumatic ones can provide you with proper traction on dry sand as well.