# How To Mount a Large Diameter Tire To A Smaller Diameter Axle?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, wheels

I am building a cart from ([What Type of Tires and Wheels Do I Need to Make a PVC Beach Cart?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/what-type-of-tires-and-wheels-do-i-need-to-make-a-pvc-beach-cart)). I have a wheel whose central diameter is 3 inches and the PVC for the axle is 1 inch in diameter. I am planning on cutting a wooden circle and attaching it to the wheel and cutting a 1.25 inch hole through the center of the wood so the PVC pipe can pass through the wood. Is this a good idea or are there better alternatives?

Here is a picture of the wheel and tire [image: Wheel and Tire]

Comment: are you purchasing trailer wheels for this project?  There are better solutions, eg https://www.wheeleez.com/polyurethane-wheel-axle-kits of course if you are utilizing some old wheels you have on hand that's a different story.  In any case this is really not an engineering topic, more diy.stackexchange material.

Comment: 3/4 inch  pvc (1 inch OD) is awful small for an axle btw. How much weight are you planning?

Comment: I agree that PVC tubing isn't likely to work. Just get some steel tubing.

Answer (score 1):

What may be significantly easier is to make an adapter plate that matches the hole pattern on the wheel hub and a pvc pipe flange. The other really easy thing to do at this point is using a frame from a new four wheeled wheelbarrow. The wheelbarrow is belt from those environment, has roughly 1 ton capacity engineered in and it saves you a ton of time which I would assume is worth way more than the wheelbarrow. I hope that this helps.

Comment: I like the flange idea. How should I attach the flange to the axle? Should I just grease both or use bearings inside the flange?